# How to set UISegmentedControl frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 30.0);
```

The result is segmentedControl has about 10 pts margin left and top.

I try to change the params of its frame but cannot change x position.
So it always has 10 pt margin left. How to remove this margin?

**Edit**

I figure it out

UIToolbar has 10pt margin. If I add only UISegmentedControl, it will display correctly.

Comment: What is your question? You want to be able to set x and y?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the margin. I want segmentedControl with screen size width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't change the height of `UISegmentedControl` because height is fixed for `UISegmentedControl` based on its style

for plain and borderd style the height is 43 and for bar style the height is 29.

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 29.0);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

set **UISegmentedControlStyleBar** in `segmentedControlStyle` property of `UISegmentedControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];  
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);  
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
```

Comment: not working, the origin of the frame is not changed?
I don't know why. It's just a subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Use setter method

```
[segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Segmented control has the rounded rect border and that is why it displayse so.Jus set some color on its background and you can see the correct frame of the segment